# What's the meaning of: "java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Error: Unknown host specified" if TNS-alias specified

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Using Oracle JDBC driver with TNS-alias instead of host:port:SID a'la

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@TNS_ALIAS
```

you may get this error message

```
java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: I/O-Error: Unknown host specified
```

while calling

```
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection
```

But there is no problem with the hostname specified by TNS-alias.

Comment: I had the same issue with SQLCL. After setting the TNS_ADMIN, it was fixed

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this error message does not point to the real reason:
The error occurs if driver cannot find the tnsnames.ora config file.

**Solution**
You have to ensure that system-property "oracle.net.tns_admin" is set before connecting and points to the directory containing the tnsnames.ora.